# How to integrate NCover and MSTest 10.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, mstest, ncover

Using [NCover Community edition](http://www.ncover.com/download/community), I tried:

```
set ncover="C:\Program Files (x86)\NCover\NCover.Console.exe"
set mstest="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
set testdllfolder="C:\.hudson\jobs\Project\workspace\src\TestProject\bin\Debug"

%ncover% //x coverage.xml //w %testdllfolder% %mstest% /noisolation /testcontainer:TestProject.dll
```

The output begins like this

> Working Directory:
>
> Assemblies:
>
> Coverage Xml: C:.hudson\jobs\Project\workspace\src\coverage.xml
>   Coverage Log: Coverage.Log
>
> Waiting for profiled application to connect...Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 10.0.30319.1

and after the MSTest output

> Test Run Failed.
>     Passed        8
>     Failed        2
>     Inconclusive   2
>
> ---
>
> Total         103
>    Results file:  C:.hudson\jobs\Project\workspace\src\debug.trx
>   Test Settings: Local
>   Connected
>   Profiled process terminated. Profiler connection not established.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the console output to your message? That'd tell if the session completed successfully. It could be that the coverage xml isn't showing because it's going to a directory other than the one you think it should. It's default is the current command prompt directory.

Also, you may want to try using the latest edition of NCover, v.3.4.16. You can get a 21-day trial for free at [www.ncover.com/download](http://www.ncover.com/download).

Comment: It worked with version 3. I'm trying to figure out how to make it work with v1.8. I posted the output in the question body. The tested assembly uses .NET Framework 3.5.